# Dynamic Input Fields Width Resize

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two fields that changes value of each other when numbers are inputted into any of them.

I need a way to change their widths as their value changes viceversa.

I have tried `onchange` `oninput` but they only work when a user manually clicks on the field and enter the value.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<input style="text-align:center;min-width:2px;width:100px" id="Field1" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 15) + 'px';">

<input style="text-align:center;min-width:2px;width:100px" id="Field2" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 15) + 'px';">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#Field1').keyup(function() {
    field1Val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (field1Val) {
      field2Val = field1Val;
      $('#Field2').val(field2Val.toFixed(8));
    }
    else {
      $('#Field2').val("")
    }
});

$('#Field2').keyup(function() {
    field2Val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (field2Val) {
      field1Val = field2Val
      $('#Field1').val(parseFloat(field1Val).toFixed(2));
    }
    else {
      $('#Field1').val("")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to use jQuery's `width` function and handle everything in your `keyup` event. This is a bit ugly but should give you the idea:

```js
var field1OriginalWidth = $('#Field1').width();
var field2OriginalWidth = $('#Field2').width();

$('#Field1').keyup(function() {
  field1Val = parseInt($(this).val());
  $(this).width(10 * $(this).val().toString().length); //Calculating the required width based on input length

  if (field1Val) {
    field2Val = field1Val;
    $('#Field2').val(field2Val.toFixed(8));
    $('#Field2').width($(this).width()) //Set the other Field's width
  } else {
    $('#Field2').val("")
    $('#Field1').width(field1OriginalWidth);
    $('#Field2').width(field2OriginalWidth); //Reset both fields to some original width
  }
});

$('#Field2').keyup(function() {

  field2Val = parseFloat($(this).val());
  $(this).width(10 * $(this).val().toString().length);
  if (field2Val) {
    field1Val = field2Val
    $('#Field1').val(parseFloat(field1Val).toFixed(2));
    $('#Field1').width($(this).width())
  } else {
    $('#Field1').val("");
    $('#Field1').width(field1OriginalWidth);
    $('#Field1').width(field1OriginalWidth);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="text-align:center;min-width:2px;width:100px" id="Field1" type="text">

<input style="text-align:center;min-width:2px;width:100px" id="Field2" type="text">
```